# Jquery load method conflict current script with child page external script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a free template with dashboard menu and the main content section. I want that when a user clicks on menu link and the child page will be loaded into the main content section. I don't want to user embed tag or iframe because of some problems so I tried Jquery load method and $.ajax.
The problem is the menu included 2 external scripts (bootstrap and jquery); when child page loaded, they didn't understand scripts of the menu. But if I put 2 more same scripts tag to child page or using $.getScript(), the child page loaded but jquery.js and bootstrap.js were seemed to be conflicted and worked on the wrong way.

main code

```
<html>
<head>// Some css link</head>
<body>
    <!-- Menu -->
    <div class="menu">
        <ul class="list">
            <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="index.html">
                    <i class="material-icons">home</i>
                    <span>Home</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="setPage('child.jsp')">
                    <i class="material-icons">text_fields</i>
                    <span>Child page</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <section class="content" id="main-content">
    </section>

    <!-- Jquery Core Js -->
    <script src="plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--Bootstrap Core Js-->
    <script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- Select Plugin Js -->
    <script src="plugins/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
    <script>
        function setPage(page) {
            $.ajax({
                url: page,
            }).done(function (data) {
                $("#main-content").html(data);
                // $.getScript("plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js");
                // $.getScript("plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js");
                // $.getScript("plugins/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.js");
                // $.getScript("plugins/jquery-countto/jquery.countTo.js")
            });

        }
    </script>
</body>
```

child code

```
    <div class="info-box bg-pink hover-expand-effect">
        <div class="icon">
            <i class="material-icons">playlist_add_check</i>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="text">NEW TASKS</div>
            <div class="number count-to" data-from="0" data-to="125" data-speed="15" data-fresh-interval="20"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If I run without $.getScript, child page loaded into section but just content and css, js didn't work. If I run with $.getScript ( or put external script inside child page) ,child page loaded with js but jquery and bootstrapsjs go wrong with some unexpected animation.

Thanks guys so much.

Comment: Put your exact code in here so we can help you fix it.

Comment: I did update with the code, thanks for your helping.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have jQuery on the page (and bootstrap) no need to add those back in. Getting content that does contain script will execute once it is on the page.  Notice I put a small bit to add a class to the menu, and it executes when loaded.

Here I "fake" the ajax using a jQuery `Deferred` - jQuery `.ajax()` returns a deferred so it really can be a good fake for that.

Note I commented out the `console.log()` to make this example cleaner but you can uncomment to see them to see what is there at each step.

Note just for clarity jQuery

`$.getScript(myurl);`

is an alias for

`$.ajax({
  url: myurl,
  dataType: "script",
  success: success
});`

SO, given that I added a fake ajax for an independent script also.

```js
// this is fake ajax content
var ccode = '<div class="info-box bg-pink hover-expand-effect"><div class="icon"><i class="material-icons">playlist_add_check</i></div><div class="content"><div class="text">NEW TASKS</div><div class="number count-to" data-from="0" data-to="125" data-speed="15" data-fresh-interval="20"></div></div></div><scr';
ccode += 'ipt>$(".menu").addClass("showAction")</scr';
ccode += 'ipt>';
// this is fake script content
var fakeScript = '<scr' + 'ipt>$("#main-content").addClass("showScriptLoaded")</scr';
fakeScript += 'ipt>';
// this is fake script content
var otherFakeScript = '<scr' + 'ipt>console.log("proof"+$(".goodchild").text());$(".goodchild").append(" says Howdy!");</scr';
otherFakeScript += 'ipt>';

// just for the demo, think of this as ajax
function getFakeAjax(deferred) {
  //console.log('in fake ajax');
  deferred.then(function(data) {
      //console.log('fake stuff then');
      return data;
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      //console.log('fake ajax data', data);
      $("#main-content").html(data);
      // kick off fakescript load
      var def2 = $.Deferred(getFakeScript);
      // pass that fake ajax object
      def2.resolve(fakeScript);
    })
    .fail(function() {});
}
// just for the demo, think of this as getScript
function getFakeScript(deferred2) {
  //console.log('in fake ajax');
  deferred2.then(function(data) {
      //console.log('fake stuff then');
      return data;
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      if (jQuery) {
        // jQuery is loaded  
        alert("Yeah! well duh we just used it");
      } else {
        // jQuery is not loaded
        alert("Doesn't Work");
      }
      //console.log('fake ajazx script', data);
      $(data).appendTo("#main-content");
    })
    .fail(function() {});
}

function setPage(page) {
  //console.log('setPage', page);
  // I used the fake for this
  //  $.ajax({
  //   url: page,
  //  }).done(function(data) {
  //   $("#main-content").html(data);
  // });

  // call the fake the ajax
  var def = $.Deferred(getFakeAjax);
  // fax ajax done (second one)
  def.done(function(data) {
    // pretend our server is slow to load first script
    // 4 seconds later kick off second fakescript load
    setTimeout(function() {
      var def2 = $.Deferred(getFakeScript);
      // pass that fake ajax object
      def2.resolve(otherFakeScript);
    }, 4000);
  })
  // pass that fake ajax object
  def.resolve(ccode);
}
```

```css
.showAction {
  border: solid lime 2px;
}

.showScriptLoaded {
  border: solid red 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
      <li class="active">
        <a href="index.html">
          <i class="material-icons">home</i>
          <span>Home</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="setPage('child.jsp')">
          <i class="material-icons">text_fields</i>
          <span class="goodchild">Child page</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <section class="content" id="main-content">get content here
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your helping but it not worked. Same as using $.ajax without scripts. Content and css were loaded but js (jquery.js) didn't work.

Comment: NOTE: you ONLY have to load jQuery once.  Once it is on the page, you can use it as much as needed.  See how I did that and did not reload it again? - note a SECOND script might also load a plugin before using it - like I included a THIRD one.  One note `.getScript()` loads in the global context.